# Can't Connect to Chain through websocket

Tags: polkadot, websocket, explorer

My Polkadot-JS explorer UI[image] does not load when i connect to the local chain and gives a websocket error.

```
 API-WS: disconnected from ws://127.0.0.1:9944: 1006:: Abnormal Closure
```

It just started this suddenly. Please how can i resolve this.

I ran the local unmodified `substrate-node-template` chain with

```
./target/release/node-template --dev
```

Comment: The error can occur if you are not running the host locally. Since you have not provided the output from the node itself we cannot know if your node is running or not.

Answer (score 1):

What you appear to be doing is running a node locally on your machine and attempting to connect to it.

As noted you have not provided any context on which node you are running or any other details.

- You should ensure that if you want to connect a UI to your node you need to have the correct arguments supplied during startup.

  - There is some very good documentation from one of the Parachain teams [here](https://docs.totemaccounting.com/#/nodes-docs/howto-setup-nodes) about setting up nodes.
  - Although it should be noted that these docs refer to using nodes that use docker containers, the [arguments](https://docs.totemaccounting.com/#/nodes-docs/howto-docker-uirpc-node?id=start-commands-for-a-uirpc-node) used to start the nodes (that will be connected to polkadotjs apps) are the same. i.e. use these:

```shell
--ws-external
--rpc-cors=all
```

The default websocket port will be `9944` and reachable from localhost or `127.0.0.1:9944`

Lastly your node must be running to connect to it!

Comment: it's the unmodified substrate node template. Tried that, still the same